# invalid-api-key Visual Recognition IBM

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson

I have a school project that is to compare 3 facial recognition APIs (IBM, AMAZON, MICROSOFT).

I want to use the IBM Visual Recognition API, but when I run my java program it always returns the error 403 invalid-api-key.

[image]

Comment: Go to the existing services page in the IBM Cloud and make sure you copy the `api_key` and `url`. See https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson/getting-started-credentials.html

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem using the java-sdk.

Solved by using the iamCredentials instead of directly using the apikey.

```
visualRecognition = new VisualRecognition("2018-05-23");
visualRecognition.setIamCredentials(new IamOptions.Builder()
    .apiKey("YOUR_API_KEY")
    .build());
```